# Invalid column name with RANK OVER function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, adventureworks

Attempting to create a table with the total quantity sold by product and select the third highest quantity sold product segmented by date. Keep getting error

> Invalid Column name

for the alias for my `RANK () OVER` statement:

```
select 
    RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY t3.orderdate order by t3.total_amt_ordered) as ranking,
    t3.productid, 
    t3.orderdate,
    t3.total_amt_ordered
from 
    (select 
         t2.productid,
         t1.orderdate,
         SUM(t2.orderqty) as total_amt_ordered 
     from
         saleslt.salesorderheader t1 
     inner join 
         saleslt.salesorderdetail t2 on t1.salesorderid = t2.salesorderid 
     group by 
         productid, orderdate) t3
where 
    ranking = 3;
```

Comment: Whats your expectation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below query will return all the product ids partitioned at order date level and all the order quantities which ranked at three.

```
SELECT * FROM
     (
        select 
                DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY t3.orderdate order by  
                t3.total_amt_ordered DESC ) as ranking,
                t3.productid, 
                t3.orderdate,
                t3.total_amt_ordered
          from ( 
                 select 
                         t2.productid,
                         t1.orderdate,
                         SUM(t2.orderqty) as total_amt_ordered 
                   from
                         saleslt.salesorderheader t1 
                     inner join
                         saleslt.salesorderdetail t2 
                     on t1.salesorderid=t2.salesorderid 
                   group by productid, orderdate) t3
      ) Z
where Z.ranking= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting error now on the where statement. Can I not include it?

Comment: What error are you getting? And also does my query work without where clause? If so what are the final columns in the output you are seeing...?

Comment: It doesn't work without where clause. Showing :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Can you try running the inner most queries and see how the results are coming out...

Comment: You need to add an alias for the Derived Table, i.e. before the final WHERE

Comment: So this code works except it's only giving me results for one of the dates (table contains two order dates 6-04 and 6-05 - only giving me results for 6-04 but it is correct for 6-04

Comment: 118 values for 6-04 and 135 for 6-05

Comment: Are there any duplicates in your ordered value at date level partition... ?? If its the case then u shud use dense rank instead of rank...

Comment: DENSE_RANK did the trick. Only weird thing is I get the 4th and 5th highest value for 6-05 (they are both the same amount) - but 6-04 is correct. Any reason I'd get the 4th value down instead of the third (the second and third value are also tied - so maybe it's in that.)

Comment: Yes if there are n values which are in tie then the following value will be assigned a rank which is n less than the rank assigned to the tied value. This concern can be solved using dense rank as all ranks are consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

WHERE is evaluated before RANK, so you can't use it directly without Derived Table/CTE, but it's also calculated after SUM, resulting in this query:

```
select *
from 
  (  select 
         t2.productid,
         t1.orderdate,
         SUM(t2.orderqty) as total_amt_ordered,
         RANK ()
         OVER (PARTITION BY t1.orderdate
               order by SUM(t2.orderqty)) as ranking
     from
         saleslt.salesorderheader t1 
     inner join 
         saleslt.salesorderdetail t2 on t1.salesorderid = t2.salesorderid 
     group by 
         productid, orderdate
  ) t3
where 
    t3.ranking = 3;
```

Comment: This gives me nulls.

Comment: @CameronWarren: NULLs? You probably need to switch to `DENSE_RANK` (or maybe to `ROW_NUMBER`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way, You cannot use ranking query and same in the where condition

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.orderdate ORDER BY t3.total_amt_ordered) AS ranking,
    t3.productid,
    t3.orderdate,
    t3.total_amt_ordered
FROM (SELECT
    t2.productid,
    t1.orderdate,
    SUM(t2.orderqty) AS total_amt_ordered
FROM saleslt.salesorderheader t1
INNER JOIN saleslt.salesorderdetail t2
    ON t1.salesorderid = t2.salesorderid
GROUP BY    productid,
            orderdate) t3)
SELECT
    *
FROM cte
WHERE ranking = 3;
```

Comment: This gives all nulls.